# Can't insert data to an SQLite DB on Android

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to make an INSERT into a SQLite database in an android app that I'm developing. 
I have an HTML form with some fields and I'm able to get the info from those fields.
When I try to make the INSERT I get an error: 'Error Processing SQL: undefined'.
Can anybody help me? I'm kind of a newbie.
Here's the code I'm using:
HTML Form

```
<form name="editNoteForm" id="editNoteForm" method="post" action="index.html">
  <label for="primeiroNome">1&#186; Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="primeiroNome" id="primeiroNome">

  <label for="utlimoNome">&Uacute;ltimo Nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="ultimoNome" id="ultimoNome">

  <label for="numeroTelefone">Telefone</label>
    <input type="number" name="numeroTelefone" id="numeroTelefone">

  <input type="submit" onclick="onSubmit();" id="editFormSubmitButton" value="Save Note">

</form>
```

Javascript Code

```
function onSubmit() {
         db.transaction(addRowDB, errorCB, successCB);
         alert('Done');
    }

    function addRowDB(tx) {
        var primeiroNome = document.getElementById('primeiroNome').value;
        var ultimoNome = document.getElementById('ultimoNome').value;
        var numeroTelefone = document.getElementById('numeroTelefone').value;
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, nome, ultimo, telefone) VALUES (null, primeiroNome, ultimoNome, numeroTelefone)');

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some JavaScript Interface on webview?

Answer (score 0):

```
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, nome, ultimo, telefone) VALUES (null, primeiroNome, ultimoNome, numeroTelefone)');
```

will insert the litteral values "primeiroNome" ...

You need to insert the values of the variables primeiroNome ... (with concatenation (+), for instance)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's really the '  '. So I look for a function that puts them before and after the variable and it work. the code is this one:

```
function sqlstr(s) {
    return "'"+s.replace(/'/g, "''")+"'";
}

    function addRowDB(tx) {
        var primeiroNome = document.getElementById('primeiroNome').value;
        var ultimoNome = document.getElementById('ultimoNome').value;
        var numeroTelefone = document.getElementById('numeroTelefone').value;
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, nome, ultimo, telefone) VALUES (null, ' + sqlstr(primeiroNome) + ', ' + sqlstr(ultimoNome) + ', ' + sqlstr(numeroTelefone) + ')');


    }
```

Thanks for the help :)